# Azure Data Factory Linked Service error- Failed to get the secret from key vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

I am creating a linked service to a remote server in Azure Data Factory v2. The remote server uses username-password authentication mechanism. I have already created a linked service to the same server using username and password both in the linked service creation window and its working fine. I would like to store the password as a secret in Azure Key vault and access that secret from Azure Data Factory.

I have the secret in Azure Key vault and i have granted the access permission to Azure Data Factory to access Azure Key Vault by adding the Access policy in Key vault. I created linked service to azure key vault and it shows 'connection successful' when i tested the connection. However, when i try to create the linked service to a remote server using Azure key vault credentials instead of password, the connection failed. The error looks like this:

Failed to get the secret from key vault, secretName: *********, secretVersion: , vaultBaseUrl:*****************. The error message is: An error occurred while sending the request. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I couldn't proceed further. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots with more details? It is really not easy to reproduce your issue according to the description only.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps that is linked in the doc to create a managed identity for your azure data factory? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity

Below powershell script can be used to associate the MSI. Using the new Azure Powershell Az Module :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -Name <dataFactoryName> -Location <region>

DataFactoryName   : ADFV2DemoFactory
DataFactoryId     : /subscriptions/<subsID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ADFV2DemoFactory
ResourceGroupName : <resourceGroupName>
Location          : East US
Tags              : {}
Identity          : Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.FactoryIdentity
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
```